# What is the best way to add an existing project to GIT hub?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, github

I am creating a new API. I have created GIT repositories for this, which has two branches.

1. Master
2. DataLibrary

My API solution resides in Master branch and DataLibrary project is in DataLibrary branch.

In my local machine i have cloned both the branches and have kept in a single folder.

```
    LocalForder 
         --> Folder1 (DataLibrary)
         --> Folder2 (Master)
```

As shown above my API solution is in **Folder1** and my data project is in **Folder2**. In my API solution i have added the existing project(Data project from Folder2). And it works perfectly fine.

I pushed the changes and when my team mate took the latest code for Master branch for him the DataProject is missing. I know if I will add the Data Project to Master branch then the problem can be resolved but is there any other way to refer a project from different branch? I mean is there any setting in VS which allows us to add a different project from a local path and push it to GIT perfectly.

Comment: You have to push `DataLibrary` branch on github.

Comment: @ParthS007, DataLibrary branch is already pushed to GitHub. I am thinking to copy the dll of the data project and add it to the API bin folder. But can it be possible to automate this process? so that whenever I do some changed to DataLibrary branch , whoever pulls the Master branch for them the dll gets updated?

Comment: If you make any changes in a different branches than master, you can always create a PR and add it to master.

Comment: @SoumyashreePattnaik, I want to know if you need code to add project to github or do it manually.